# "..." is expected ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry i'm sure the this subject have copy but i don't find anything in search with "...".

This is the line with the poblem:

```
<button {this.loadApi()}>DRILLLLLL ON !!!</button>
```

this is the head of my class:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        all: '',
    };
}

loadApi(){
    this.setState({ all: myApiGet('https://*******') });
}
```

I success use this function in a Onclick button but i want load it in the first load of the page and i'm stuck....

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `but i want load it in the first load of the page` Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this.loadApi()
}
Like this ?  Never use that i must work on react for help but im new in this langage.

Comment: Work ! Thanks So much <3

Comment: ReactJS so hard :(

Answer (score 0):

I post an aswer to this resolved post for sk you one more thing related.

Resume:

I have a .jsx with a parent class and a child, in the parent i initialize the api and stock the json content in a state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        all: '',
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadApi();
}

loadApi(){
    this.setState({ all: myApiGet('https://******') });
}
```

After that i need to get the "url" of the differents pics for show them on the site. But there is the problem, I get the api json when i load the page and i don't success to re-load the function.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.apiGetProductPicture(nextProps.categorie);
}

apiGetProductPicture = (i) => () => {
        // TODO do something with the data
    var stock = this.props.all
        .then(stock => this.setState({ pictures: stock.content.categories[i].background }))

        .catch(error => console.log('home2', error));
}
```

I try a lot of possibility and check the net but the solution doesn't work for me (or i just doesn't understand them ...)

Thanks for your time :/